# Declaration of std::sort functor

Tags: c++, stl, visual-studio-2012

This is how my source code looks (simplified):

```
class UncertaintyTest
{
private:
    class SpectralPeak
    {
    };

    std::list<SpectralPeak*> peaks;
};

struct SpectralPeakComparator
{
   bool operator()(const UncertaintyTest::SpectralPeak &a, const UncertaintyTest::SpectralPeak &b)
   {
      return a.TMiddleAvg() < b.TMiddleAvg();
   }
};

void UncertaintyTest::SortSpectralPeaks()
{
   std::sort(peaks.begin(), peaks.end(), SpectralPeakComparator());
}
```

The compiler refuses to compile this source code with following errors:

```
 C2676: binary '-' : 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm    3868    1   Periodogram
 C2780: 'void std::_Sort(_RanIt,_RanIt,_Diff)' : expects 3 arguments - 4 provided   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm    3868    1   Periodogram
 C2784: ''unknown-type' std::operator -(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm    3868    1   Periodogram
 C2784: ''unknown-type' std::operator -(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm    3868    1   Periodogram
 C2784: ''unknown-type' std::operator -(std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm    3868    1   Periodogram
 C2784: 'std::complex<_Other> std::operator -(const _Ty &,const std::complex<_Other> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::complex<_Other> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm    3868    1   Periodogram
 C2784: 'std::complex<_Other> std::operator -(const std::complex<_Other> &,const _Ty &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::complex<_Other> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm    3868    1   Periodogram
 C2784: 'std::complex<_Other> std::operator -(const std::complex<_Other> &,const std::complex<_Other> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::complex<_Other> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm    3868    1   Periodogram
```

The problematic line is that with `std:sort`. If I comment it, all is OK. What is wrong in my declaration of the comparator object?

Comment: `peaks` holds pointers. Your functor does not compare pointers.

Comment: The 2nd line says `_RanIt` - `list` doesn't have random access iterators.

Comment: Prefer a vector of pointers instead of list as it is more efficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is twofold:

Firstly, the sort functor does not accept the correct value type. Your list holds pointers, not objects directly, so the comparison functor has to work with pointers as well:

```
struct SpectralPeakComparator
{
   bool operator()(const UncertaintyTest::SpectralPeak *a, const UncertaintyTest::SpectralPeak *b)
   {
      return a->TMiddleAvg() < b->TMiddleAvg();
   }
};
```

Secondly, `std::list` does not have random access iterators, which `std::sort` requires. You can instead use `std::list::sort`:

```
peaks.sort(SpectralPeakComparator());
```